# Pandas '9999-12-31' datetime representation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I`m trying to read into pandas dataframe a csv file with two columns containing dates:

```
customer_id,name,surname,date_from,date_to
1,John,Smith,2010-01-04,2018-09-06
2,Jake,Sarti,2011-09-02,2017-11-03
3,Jim,Sayer,2012-06-12,9999-12-31
4,James,Scheer,2011-09-02,9999-12-31
```

While date_from is a column of datetime64[ns] as expected, the problem in date_to seems to be 'end of the world' dates.

This obviously is a consequence of nanosecond granularity of datetime64.

I thought about using converters parameter, but I`m not sure if it will be an efficient way.

The problem with read_csv also occurs with read_sql while reading date columns containing hight dates.

I already tried `na_values = ['9999-12-31']` , which works, but I would be forced to change the way we select valid records in our database environment and calculate fields indicating not valid records.

```
import pandas as pd
cust = pd.read_csv('customers.csv', parse_dates=['date_from', 'date_to'])

cust.dtypes
```

```
[Out]
customer_id             int64
name                   object
surname                object
date_from      datetime64[ns]
date_to                object
dtype: object
```

Is it possible to downgrade datetime type granularity to days, hours, .., seconds so reading csv and databases will not require manipulation of data in datetime column?

Comment: you just want to to convert your date_from into days and hours,seconds?

Comment: You could try something like this: `df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), converters={'date_to': lambda ds: datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y-%m-%d').date()}, sep=',')` but this uses python dates to store the dates and you might problems with your followup operations and they are stored as object which is not as efficient as storing the value in a numpy array, but at least you can store dates like `9999-12-31` this way.